# Rails mysql ELF header error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, virtualbox

Im trying to start my rails application on ubuntu 11.10, but im hitting the following error:

`<PROJECT_PATH>/vendor/cache/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: invalid ELF header - <PROJECT_PATH>/vendor/cache/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so`

Im running this in a virtual machine (host: Windows 7, guest: Ubuntu 11.10) if that makes a difference.

Ive pulled out half the hair on my head, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im quite embarrassed, but just in case there is someone else out there and faces something like this because of his/her stupidity,

the error was because the folder was being shared between windows and linux, and bundler had been run on windows earlier. When on ubuntu, the earlier installed windows libraries were being picked up, instead of the native linux ones. Cleaning the `vendor/cache` fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to @zsquare's answer I encountered the same problem when copied a whole **deployed** project from 32-bit Ubuntu machine to 64-bit.
Unfortunately his answer didn't help, but my solution was even easier: just **deleted** the whole project and **re-deployed** it again.