# I have an error while running ruby server (RMX-OS)

Tags: ruby, server

i have this error when i launch RMX-OS.rb

root@Pokemon-Paradiz:~/RMX-OS# ruby RMX-OS.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': /root/RMX-OS/bin/2.0/mysql_api.so: invalid ELF header - /root/RMX-OS/bin/2.0/mysql_api.so (LoadError) from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in` require'
from RMX-OS.rb:72:in `'

please help me ,
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431044/rails-mysql-elf-header-error) ?